# Success from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax

So, I have two JavaScript functions:

```
function Generate() {
  //Do something
  $.ajax({data:{Svc: 'cpMain',
                Cmd: 'Generate'
               },
     dataType: "text",
     context: this,
     success: genSuccess()
   });
}

function genSuccess() {
  //Do something
}
```

and in my c#, on `Page_Init()` I pick up the parameters from my AJAX callback to do something.

I want the order to be `Generate()`, callback, `genSuccess()`. But the order in which this is running is `Generate()`, `genSuccess()`, callback.

Am I missing something?

Comment: when you type `genSuccess()` you're calling the method.  I think in this case you can get away with `genSuccess` without paranthesis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provide the function reference of `genSuccess` to `success`, and not the return value of a call to `genSuccess`

```
success: genSuccess
```